# How can I determine whether ${x_n}$ converges in $(C[0,1],\|\centerdot\|_1)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

where $$x_n(t)=
\begin{cases}
nt & 0\leq t<\frac{1}{n}\\
\frac{1}{nt}&\frac{1}{n}<t\leq 1\\
\end{cases}$$

I don't think this is converging just by guess, but what is the procedure for determining convergence? This being a function makes it a little harder for me to understand.

What is $x_1$?

Comment: It should really be $0\leq t\leq\frac{1}{n}$ and/or $\frac{1}{n}\leq t\leq 1$ to specify that $x_n(1/n)=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: I suggest computing $\int_0^1 x_n(t)dt$.

Comment: $x_1$ is not the constant function over $[0,1]$ - it's the identity function $x(t)=t$.

Comment: Have you tried to draw a sketch of the function's graph? It is usually extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph of $f_n$ consists of a straight line segment from the origin to the point $[1/n,1]$ and a "hyberbolic arch" from $[1/n,1]$ to $[1,1/n]$.

Note that $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to 0:
For $t=0$, we have $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$, while
for $t>0$:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(t)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} {1\over nt}=0.
$$

Now note:

- The distance from any $f_n$ to the 0 function in $C[0,1]$ is 1.
- $\int_0^1| f_n(t)-0|\,dt= {1\over 2n}+ \int_{1/n}^1 {1\over
     n}{1\over t}\,dt= {1\over n}+ {\ln n\over n}$.

[image]